# AWS Cognito, Angular, doesn't recognize Identity Pool ID

Tags: angular, amazon-cognito

I'm using Angular 4, and trying to authenticate a given user after I have recieved the SAML response from my IdP but AWS returns a '400 Identity Pool ID not found' error.

I verified that it is the correct id that the aws console shows, and everything is in the same region (us-west-2).

Here's the relevant code:

```
//Initialize

  let cognitoIdentity = new AWS.CognitoIdentity({apiVersion: 'latest', region: environment.cognitoRegion});

  cognitoIdentity.config.credentials = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityCredentials({IdentityPoolId: environment.identityPoolId});
  cognitoIdentity.config.update({accessKeyId: 'anything', secretAccessKey: 'anything'})

//Setup params for authentication

  var params = {
        IdentityId: environment.identityPoolId,
        Logins: {
            [environment.SAMLProviderARN]: '<super long base64 saml response>'
        }
    };

//Get credentials for user

  cognitoIdentity.getCredentialsForIdentity(params, function(err, data) {
        //log error or sucessful response
        if (err){
            console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
        }
        else {
            console.log(data);           // successful response
        }
    });
```

> identityPoolId: 'us-west-2:52xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxd0'
>
> cognitoRegion: 'us-west-2'
>
> SAMLProviderARN: arn:aws:iam::(accountID):saml-provider/secpov-shibboleth

But I still get 400 "ResourceNotFoundException: Identity 'us-west-2:52...d0' not found."

Comment: Can you share your 'environment' variables? I can check the Cognito datastore to see what the pool looks like.

Comment: Updated w/ info

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're seeing this 400 error is because you are assigning your "IdentityPoolId" into the "IdentityId" property of your parameters array.

In your parameters array change the name of the property to IdentityPoolId. That will resolve this 400 error.

Comment: So that makes sense however when I tried that, it returned that IdentityPoolId is an unrecognized param and that the IdentityId was required:
`Error: There were 2 validation errors:
 * MissingRequiredParameter: Missing required key 'IdentityId' in params
 * UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'IdentityPoolId' found in params`
I also then tried to use the IdentityId and it said `Value 'us-west-2_IjGKTnExQ' at 'identityId' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [\w-]+:[0-9a-f-]+`
So, it does need the id to be the pool id, but won't recognize mine